# For loop print in single line separated by spaces - JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, console.log

Helllo,

I have easy question, but can't find the solution. Need to print all numbers from 1 to N (10) but not in a row. The output needs to bee in single line separated by spaces - 1 2 3 4 5...

```
let n = 10;
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Can I do it without using array?

Comment: so build a string and write that out or array with join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate with a string in the loop instead, then `console.log` that string:

```js
let n = 10;
let str = '';
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  str += i + ' ';
}
console.log(str.trim());
```

Comment: Thanks you, this is really easy way.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach could be to create an array using fill and map to create an array, then join the values to create the string.

```js
let n = 10
let r = new Array(n).fill(null).map((val, idx) => idx + 1).join(' ')

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one idea with arrays and map, but it was different.